# Group Values in a data structure

Tags: python, django

I'm pretty new to the world of Django / Python.

I have a the following query in a manager :

```
listOfHeroes = self.all().values('user__user__username','skill','level')
```

It return a table like this:

```
[{'user__user__username': u'Aragorn', 'skill': 'Fireball', 'level': 5}, {'user__user__username': u'Leonidas', 'skill': 'sword', 'level': 1},{'user__user__username': u'Aragorn', 'skill': 'sword', 'level': 4},....]
```

I want to group my data by heroes. I mean Aragorn has two skills Fireball and Sword :

```
User: Aragorn / Skills: { sword level 4 / fireball level 5}
```

Final datas I have where skills are grouped by User must be easily iterable.

If you have any ideas... I've tried to create a dictionary but I failed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to change your database query, use this:

```
result = {}
for item in listOfHeroes:
    if item['user__user__username'] not in result:
        result[item['user__user__username']] = []
    result[item['user__user__username']].append({'skill': item['skill'], 'level': item['level']})

for key, value in result.items():
    print 'User: {0} / Skills: {{ {1} }}'.format(key, ' / '.join(['{0} level {1}'.format(skill['skill'], skill['level']) for skill in value]))
```

Comment: It renders something like :
    {u'Aragorn': ['Fireball', 'Sword'], u'Leonidas': ['sword']...
Is it possible to have something like a dictionary : {'user''Aragorn,skills:{[skill:'fireball',level:5][skill:'sword',level4}}{user:'leonidas'....

Comment: Alex Grs - Check my update, Your requested dictionary is bad formatted.